# Prove that $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty {\ln(k) \over k^2} \le{2+3\ln2 \over 4} $

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty{\ln(k) \over k^2} \le{2+3\ln2 \over 4}  $$

Start with

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n {\ln(k) \over k^2} \le \int_1^n {\ln(x) \over x^2}\,dx + f(1) $$

where

$$ f(x) = {\ln(x) \over x^2} $$

Thus, if we integrate we get that

$$  \int_1^\infty {\ln(x) \over x^2}\,dx + f(1) = 1 $$

Now, assuming everything I did above is correct, how do I show that

$$ 1  \le{2+3\ln2 \over 4} $$

without the help of a calculator?

Comment: This is equivalent to $\frac{2}{3} \leq \ln 2$.

Comment: There is some confusion with $\infty$ and $n$ in the limits of the sum and integral. Can you correct that?

Comment: By the way, if it happens that you are a student at Lund University, you might be interested in the local forum.maths.lth.se where you can ask in swedish.

Comment: Might consider that, but I really like how quick people are able to provide answers on mathematics.

Comment: This inequality is pretty close since $-\zeta'(2)=0.9375482543$ and $\frac{2+3\log(2)}4=1.0198603854$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem with your solution is that you compare the sum with integral on an interval where the function $\frac{\ln x}{x^2}$ is not decreasing. In fact the function is decreasing from 2 on (show that!).

Also, the sum is zero when you insert $k=1$, so your sum equals $\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln k}{k^2}$.

Thus, what you get, using the same method as you write about, is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln k}{k^2}=\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln k}{k^2}\leq \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^2}\, dx+\frac{\ln 2}{2^2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks again, Micke! I was under the impressions that it started decreasing from 1, but now I realize how ridiculous that is :) It's all in the details, as usual.

Comment: So, I just differentiated the function, and it seems like the maxium point (where it starts decreasing) is actually sqrt(e)?

Comment: Indeed, and that is between 1 and 2. My "from 2 on" might have been a bit vague...

Comment: Awesome, totally understand now.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative bound can be derived from:
$$\forall n\geq 2,\quad \log(n) \leq H_n-\gamma-\frac{1}{2n+1},\tag{1}$$
leading to:
$$ \sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{\log k}{k^2}\leq \frac{10}{3}+\gamma-\zeta(2)-\gamma\zeta(2)-4\log 2+2\zeta(3) < 1.\tag{2} $$
Since $e^2<8$,$\frac{2+3\log 2}{4}>1$, so we're done.